# zend2 - расширение фреймворка через наследование

Tags: php, mvc, zend-framework-2

Подскажите пожалуйста, насколько архитектурно правильно в контексте ZF2 (3) расширять классы фреймворка через наследование?

Например класс Mvc контроллера, модуля, класс ViewResolver-а, классы Manager-ов(Service,Module,Event), классы ORM.

Почему возникает вопрос:
В ZF1 это был штатный способ тюнинга фреймворка - альтернатив тюна фреймворка не было, в плюс к тому что через наследование весьма удобно было сделать "свой фреймворк". В ZF2 существует событийная система - всё делается через события, через перехват событий можно радикально поменять работу большинства компонентов, в том числе компонентов ядра.

Появляется альтернатива - там где можно: использовать события, там где нет - наследование. Но это выглядит не совсем корректно с точки зрения ООП, да и решать всё через наследование привычнее чем разбираться в событиях ядра зенда и порядке их выполнения. При каком пути проект будет гибче, и с ним будет работать проще seniour-программистам?